# In a Rails form how to use Jquery to hide and unhide form elements? My scripts won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In Rails I have a form which edit multiple records at a time. I want to show some elements only if a checkbox is ticked. Here's the javascript I wrote :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Initially if free is checked hide nonfree options else show
        if ($('<%= "#submits_#{submitid}_free" %>').attr('value') == '1') {
            $('<%= "#submits_#{submitid}_revealnonfree" %>').hide();
        } else {
            $('<%= "#submits_#{submitid}_revealnonfree" %>').show();
        }

        // Initiall if sell rights is checked show prices or else hide
        if ($('<%= "#submits_#{submitid}_sellrights" %>').attr('value') == '1') {
            $('<%= "#submits_#{submitid}_revealrights" %>').show();
        } else {
            $('<%= "#submits_#{submitid}_revealrights" %>').hide();
        }

        // If free checked hide nonfree
        $('<%= "#submits_#{submitid}_free" %>').change(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                $('<%= "#submits_#{submitid}_revealnonfree" %>').fadeOut('slow');
            } else {
                $('<%= "#submits_#{submitid}_revealnonfree" %>').fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });

        //If sell rights checked show prices
        $('<%= "#submits_#{submitid}_sellrights" %>').change(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                $('<%= "#submits_#{submitid}_revealrights" %>').fadeIn('slow');
            } else {
                $('<%= "#submits_#{submitid}_revealrights" %>').fadeOut('slow');
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

I load it after every record. The script does hide and unhide elements when the correct check box values are changed. But if the checkbox is ticked on the beginning when the page loads, the script won't show the necessary elements. The first part of the script should do that but it doesn't. Here's my form source code without the scripts : http://pastebin.com/Vj9HbrEB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply trigger the change event once for each checkbox, ad this to the end of your script:

```
    $('<%= "#submits_#{submitid}_free" %>').trigger('change')
    $('<%= "#submits_#{submitid}_sellrights" %>').trigger('change')
```

Comment: It should work, can you pop a `console.log` in your on change listener and make sure my two lines are after the change listeners are added?

Comment: Yes it worked! I have accidentally placed it after document.ready function. Thanks!